# Standard way of computing a single ECDSA signature hex string from its tuple form

Tags: rust, digital-signature, ecdsa

I implemented ECDSA manually in rust, where the output is signature in the form of a tuple (r,s). I wanted to test my implementation, and therefore I was looking for functions in python or rust for verifying the signature (r,s) given the public key, message and the curve details. The [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm) also shows the output signature in tuple form.

But, everywhere I looked, the signature is inputted as a single hex string or a byte array. Can someone please share any way of converting (r,s) pair to the hex string. I tried concatenation but got wrong result in my algo.

If it is helpful, I tried using the crate secp256k1 in rust for verification.

Comment: Ring has [EcdsaKeyPair::from_private_key_and_public_key](https://docs.rs/ring/latest/ring/signature/struct.EcdsaKeyPair.html#method.from_private_key_and_public_key)

Comment: @Holloway I am intending to verify a signature that my program produced ,while EcdsaKeyPair::from_private_key_and_public_key verifies the correctness of the pair of keys (not the signatures) right ?